# how to configure log4j in a web application using jboss 7.1.1?

Tags: log4j

The steps to configure log4j are:
Step 1.
Create the file: jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>    
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Step 2.
Create the servlet: Log4jInitServlet.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

public class Log4JInitServlet extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3677208571865966932L;
    private static final Log log=LogFactory.getLog(Log4JInitServlet.class);

    public Log4JInitServlet(){

    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request
            ,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.write("<h1>LogTester Application Version Guide Erasmo Marciano 1.0</h1>");
            out.write("<p>Loading this page generates multiple log events for the it.deinformatica.marciano.logtest category.</p>");
            out.write("<p>Click on F5 reload this web-page.</p>");
            out.write("<p>You wii find level log:debug|fatal|error|trace|info|warn</p>");
            out.close();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                log.debug("This is DEBUG message. Event number " + i);
                log.fatal("This is FATAL message. Event number " + i);
                log.info("This is INFO message. Event number " + i);
                log.error("This is ERROR message. Event number " + i);
                log.trace("This is TRACE message. Event number " + i);
                log.warn("This is WARN message. Event number " + i);
            }

    }

      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,

                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

Step 3.
create the file log4j.properties

```
### set log levels - for more verbose logging change 'info' to 'debug' ###

log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

What happens is that only shows INFO messages and no DEBUG. What am I doing wrong
or should do to display messages with lo4j DEBUG?
Please if anyone had a similar problem and solved it.

Comment: It says "change info to debug". Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced problem for Jboss EAP 6. I have resolved. My working code is like follows:

## 1. WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>    
        <exclusions>
            <!-- first exclude -->
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>            
        </exclusions>       
        <dependencies>
            <!-- then include filtered -->
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems> <subsystem name="jpa" /> </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>   
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

## 2.  resources/log4j.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, INF, DBG, ERR

#---------------------------------------------
# Redirect log messages to a log file
#---------------------------------------------

# Output to Tomcat home
logs.dir=${jboss.home}/standalone/log/
logs.fmt.dly=.yyyy-MM-dd
logs.fmt.date=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# DEBUG Logs
log4j.appender.DBG.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DBG.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
#log4j.appender.DBG.filter.LevelMin=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DBG.filter.LevelMax=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DBG.filter.AcceptOnMatch=True
log4j.appender.DBG=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DBG.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/app-debug-log.log
log4j.appender.DBG.DatePattern=${logs.dly.ptrn}
log4j.appender.DBG.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.DBG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${logs.fmt.date}} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] - %m%n

# INFO Logs
log4j.appender.INF=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.INF.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/app-info-log.log
log4j.appender.INF.DatePattern=${logs.fmt.dly}
log4j.appender.INF.Threshold=INFO
#log4j.appender.DBG.filter.LevelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.DBG.filter.LevelMax=INFO
log4j.appender.INF.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.INF.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${logs.fmt.date}} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] - %m%n



# ERROR Logs
log4j.appender.ERR=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ERR.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/app-err-log.log
log4j.appender.ERR.DatePattern=${logs.fmt.dly}
log4j.appender.ERR.Threshold=ERROR
#log4j.appender.DBG.filter.LevelMin=ERROR
#log4j.appender.DBG.filter.LevelMax=ERROR
log4j.appender.ERR.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.ERR.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${logs.fmt.date}} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude even jboss logging, and slf4j if you use it.
Remenber the xmlns in your xml, and put the file in WEB-INF folder of your webapp:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="org.log4j"/>  
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/> 
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```